# How to ensure that no more than one item in an array has a particular value in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

Given a JSON array like this:

```
[
  {
    "description": "Foo",
    "selected": false
  },
  {
    "description": "Bar",
    "selected": true
  },
  {
    "description": "Baz",
    "selected": false
  }
]
```

validated using this schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "description": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
      },
      "selected": {
        "type": "boolean"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "description",
      "selected"
    ]
  }
}
```

How could the schema be modified so that the array would pass validation only if no more than one of the items has its `selected` property set to `true`? That is, either zero or one object with that value would be considered valid, but two or more would not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `contains`/`minContains`/`maxContains` keywords. `contains` means that at least one item in the array must pass the given schema. `minContains` and `maxContains` allow you to specify upper and lower bounds for how many of the items `contains` can match.

The following schema says, there must be between 0 and 1 items in the array that are an object with a property called "selected" whose value is `true`.

```
{
  ...
  "contains": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "selected": { "const": true }
    },
    "required": ["selected"]
  },
  "minContains": 0,
  "maxContains": 1
}
```

Note that `minContains` and `maxContains` are new in draft 2019-09. Prior that that, there's not good way to limit the number of items `contains` can match. Try it out at https://json-schema.hyperjump.io